# Get file content from server, should I send the content or File-object itself?

Tags: java

If I want to get the file contents from a file located at a server through Sockets, what would be the best way to approach it?

If we assume the remote file is a multiline text file, would it be wiser to transfer the `File`-object, or should I read its contents and flatten it to one `String`? Should I return a `String[]` or perhaps an `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by sending a `java.io.File` object through sockets- generally you're going to be sending a stream of bytes (i.e. a string). The File object is just a reference to the local file; writing `new File("something.txt");` doesn't cause "something.txt" to be loaded.

So yes, the best solution would probably be to send a String.

Comment: If the File-object is just a reference to the local file then that makes sense. I thought File-objects were populated with the content from the File, but alas! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the contents if the file is located on a remote machine.
A File object would not be helpful in this case as it is just a path reference.